# 2D color map with XYZ data in matplotlib

Tags: dictionary, colors, matplotlib, 2d

I have three column data sets from a simulation given in the form

```
x, y, z
```

looking like this:

```
0.0000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+000   1.00000000000000
0.0000000E+00  0.200000002980232        1.00000000000000
0.0000000E+00  0.400000005960464        1.00000000000000
0.0000000E+00  0.600000008940697        1.00000000000000
0.0000000E+00  0.800000011920929        1.00000000000000
0.0000000E+00   1.00000001490116        1.00000000000000

0.1000000      0.000000000000000E+000  0.974332364008348
0.1000000      0.200000002980232       0.974332364008348
0.1000000      0.400000005960464       0.974332364008348
0.1000000      0.600000008940697       0.974332364008348
0.1000000      0.800000011920929       0.974332364008348
0.1000000       1.00000001490116       0.974332364008348

0.2000000      0.000000000000000E+000  0.999148125725412
0.2000000      0.200000002980232       0.999148125725412
0.2000000      0.400000005960464       0.999148125725412
0.2000000      0.600000008940697       0.999148125725412
0.2000000      0.800000011920929       0.999148125725412
0.2000000       1.00000001490116       0.999148125725412

...
```

I would like to make a 2D color map plot of my XYZ data, where x and y are simply coordinates and z is a value for each one of those points.

In GNUPLOT this is done quite easily:

if I use

```
set pm3d map

splot 'datafile.txt'
```

I obtain the right plot.

But now I was wondering how to accomplish this in matplotlib.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you stuck importing the data into python, or on plotting it once you have it?

Comment: Actually, I can read the data from the file via "genfromtxt(...)" 
and store everything in x, y, z variables. But then I don't know 
how to obtain the same plot as I would do with gnuplot.

Comment: you should either post that code, or start from the assumption that you have `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Also, look up `imshow` and `pcolor`

Answer (score 2):

My X and Y values are arrays as shown below:

```
 x_vals = np.linspace(500, 40000, 160)
 y_vals = np.linspace(100, 5000, 50)
```

My Z values are a 2D array, calculated in a loop something like:

```
z_vals = []
for this_y in y_vals:
    this_z = []
    for this_x in x_vals:
        this_val = gain_for_position(this_x, this_y, val_a, val_b)
        this_z.append(this_val)
    z_vals.append(this_z)
```

The plot I have was drawn with the following code:

```
plt.contourf(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, 8)
contour_labels = plt.contour(x_vals, y_vals,
                             z_vals, 8, colors='black', linewidth=.5)
plt.clabel(contour_labels, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

And resulted in a plot like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have revisited this code and thought a more direct example would be more useful to anyone stumbling upon this several years later.  The following code will run on the actual data provided, using python 3 and the .

The data import is a little messy, and could probably be simplified by using pandas, but I wanted to keep the imports to a minimum.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path


def get_data_from_file():
    """hard coded example for use on stack overflow"""

    raw_data = list()
    input_filename = Path(__file__).parent / "source_data_2.txt"
    with open(input_filename, "r") as input_file:
        line_count = 0
        for each_line in input_file:
            line_count += 1
            this_data = each_line.split()
            this_row = list()
            this_row.append(float(this_data[0].strip()))
            this_row.append(float(this_data[1].strip()))
            this_row.append(float(this_data[2].strip()))
            raw_data.append(this_row)

    return raw_data


def plot_projection(csv_data):
    """3D projection"""

    X = [this_v[0] for this_v in csv_data]
    Y = [this_v[1] for this_v in csv_data]
    Z = [this_v[2] for this_v in csv_data]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c="red")
    plt.show()


def plot_contour(csv_data):
    """Alternate plot"""

    size_x = 3
    size_y = 6

    x_vals = list()
    y_vals = list()
    z_vals = list()

    for y_index in range(0, size_y):
        this_row = list()
        y_vals.append(csv_data[y_index][1])
        for x_index in range(0, size_x):
            x_to_use = x_index * size_y
            if y_index == 0:
                x_vals.append(csv_data[x_to_use][0])
            this_row.append(csv_data[x_to_use + y_index][2])
        z_vals.append(this_row)

    print(f"{z_vals}")
    plt.contourf(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, 8)
    cont_labels = plt.contour(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, 8, colors="black", linewidth=0.5)
    plt.clabel(cont_labels, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_data = get_data_from_file()
    # plot_projection(csv_data)
    plot_contour(csv_data)
```

It produced the following contour plot:
[image]
If you modify the last two lines to run "plot_projection" instead, you will get the following 3D projection:
[image]

I tested the code on a similar modified dataset that was less symmetric to confirm it was doing the right thing.